# Задача про улитку

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Улитка ползет по вертикальному шесту высотой H метров, поднимаясь за день на A метров, а за ночь спускаясь на B метров. На какой день улитка доползет до вершины шеста?

Пытался решить таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long long int H, A, B;
    cin >> H >> A >> B;
    cout << (H / (A - B) - (A - (H % (A - B))) / (A - B)) + 1;
return 0;
}
```

Но программа падает на 5 тесте. Какой же алгоритм решения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Минимальное `n`, при котором

```
(A - B) * (n - 1) + A >= H
```

то есть

```
n = ceiling((H - A) / (A - B)) + 1
```

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить?

Comment: H = 10, A = 4, B = 1, `(10-4)/(4-1) = 2`, хотя должно быть `3`.

Comment: Без вещественной арифметики: `(H - B - 1) // (A - B) +  1`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a,h,b; 
cin>> h>> a>> b ;
double days = ((h-a)>=0) ? h-a:0; 
days = ceil(days/(a-b))+1;
cout<<days<<endl;

 }
```

Проблема была в том, что нужно было использовать числа с плавающей точкой и делать округления, вместо использования целых чисел

Comment: Не обязательно (см. комментарий к другому ответу)